# Receive image via PHP curl, then upload to S3

Tags: php, curl, amazon-s3

I am using PHP CURL to generate a customized PNG image from a REST API. Once this image has loaded I would like to upload it into an AWS S3 Bucket and show the link to it.

Here's my script so far:

```
$ch = curl_init();
$timeout = 5;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://url-to-generate-image.com?options=' + $_GET['options']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
$info=curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close($ch);

//require S3 Class
if (!class_exists('S3')) {
    require_once('S3.php');
}

//AWS access info
if (!defined('awsAccessKey')) {
    define('awsAccessKey', 'MY_ACCESS_KEY');
}
if (!defined('awsSecretKey')) {
    define('awsSecretKey', 'MY_SECRET_KEY');
}

//instantiate the class
$s3 = new S3(awsAccessKey, awsSecretKey);
$s3->putBucket('bucket-name', S3::ACL_PUBLIC_READ);

$file_name = md5(rand(99,99999999)) + '-myImage.png';

if ($s3->putObjectFile($data, 'bucket-name' , $file_name, S3::ACL_PUBLIC_READ)) {

    echo 'success';

    $gif_url = 'http://bucket-name.s3.amazonaws.com/'.$file_name;

} else {

    echo 'failed';

}
```

It keeps failing. Now, I think the problem is with where I use `putObjectFile` - the `$data` variable represents the image, but maybe it has to be passed in another way?

I am using a common PHP Class for S3: http://undesigned.org.za/2007/10/22/amazon-s3-php-class

Comment: A brief look at the class makes me think that the library is expecting the first param to be a file path, not file data. If it's not a file or not accessible, it runs `trigger_error('S3::inputFile(): Unable to open input file: '.$file, E_USER_WARNING);` and returns false.

Comment: @JonStirling - Thank you, you're right. I've been googling around and can't even make out IF there is a way to upload file data to S3..

Comment: @Mortimer check my answer then.

Comment: i highly recommend you to not use that class because it too old 2011 and not updated than since

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use PHP memory wrapper to store the contents of the image, and use `$s3->putObject()` method:

```
$fp = fopen('php://memory', 'wb');
fwrite($fp, $data);
rewind($fp);
$s3->putObject([
    'Bucket' => $bucketName,
    'Key' => $fileName,
    'ContentType' => 'image/png',
    'Body' => $fp,
]);
fclose($fp);
```

Proven method (you *may* need to alter the code a bit) with PHP 5.5 and latest AWS libraries.

http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php